# Record 5.1 Surround Sound

Tags: hardware, audio

I want to record audio for 5.1 Surround sound. My goal is to use 5 diy shotgun microphones with electret microphones being connected to a rpi that records and encodes to something like ac3 or at least 5 or 6 wav files(I don't need the low frequencies in the .1 but it's nice to have).

Is there a project out there that I can build upon?

Answer (score 0):

Recording 5.1 sound is generally not done. 5.1 sound is created with post processing:
https://www.filmmakingstuff.com/record-surround-sound/